# Entity of type 'StandardValueSet' named 'ProviderType' cannot be found - Health Cloud

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, health-cloud

I have added some custom picklist values in the ProviderType field
(Healthcare Provider object) which is part of the Health Cloud package. I was not able to retrieve the metadata using StandardValueSet.

[image]

Also, ProviderType field is not mentioned in the Salesforce document - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm

Regards,

Numaan M

Answer (score 1):

Got this API name from Salesforce support. StandardValueSet API name for Provider Type field in Healthcare Provider object is **HProviderProviderType**

[image]

Comment: How were you able to find a name? Is there a way to list all StandardValueSets on the org? I am trying to find names for CodeSet.CodeSetType and CodeSetBundle.Type fields.

Comment: Contact Salesforce support. Currently, you cannot retrieve all stanadardValueSets.